# How to concatenate data from different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone explain me, step by step how can i do this sort of exercise?

Let's say that i have 2 tables

- users[id, user_name, book_id]
- book[id, title, date]

How can i get this structure:

```
[user_name, list_of_book_and_dates].
```

Something like

```
 John | book1 at 10.10.2019, book2 at 15.15.2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need a LISTAGG function -

```
SELECT U.user_name, LISTAGG(B.title || 'at' || B.date, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.date)
FROM users U
JOIN book B ON U.book_id = B.id
GROUP BY U.user_name
```

If you strictly need to use RECURSIVE CTE method, You can use -

```
WITH TMP AS (SELECT U.user_name, B.title || 'at' || B.date book_detail, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_name) RN
             FROM users U
             JOIN book B ON U.book_id = B.id),
 cte AS (SELECT user_name, book_detail, RN
         FROM TMP
         WHERE RN = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT T.user_name, C.book_detail || ', ' || T.book_detail, C.RN+1
         FROM TMP T
         JOIN cte C ON U.id = C.id
         WHERE T.user_name = C.user_name
         and C.RN + 1 = T.rn)
SELECT user_name, book_detail 
FROM cte C1
WHERE RN = (SELECT MAX(RN)
            FROM cte C2
            WHERE C1.user_name = C2.user_name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick. However, how can i do this in a recursive way?

Comment: What do you mean by `recursive way`?

Comment: With 'recursive with' if it's possible

Comment: I don't see any need here to use recursive CTE here specially. Do you still need it strictly?

Comment: I have to do a homework and it specifies that i need to do something similar using recursive queries. the listagg function is nice and seems like the way to go but i would like to understand how i can do it using recursive queries